# The graph of a continuous function from a space $X$ into a Hausdorff space $Y$ is closed in $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a any topological space, $Y$ a Hausdorff space, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous map.  The graph of $f$ is defined as the subspace
>
> $$G_f :=\{(x,f(x)) \in X \times Y \mid x \in X\}.$$
>
> Show that $G_f$ is a closed subspace.

Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, I know there are open nbhds $U_y$ and $U_{f(s)}$ such that the intersection of the two is the null set.  Take $(x,y) \notin G_f$, I believe I can show that the intersection of $U$ and $G_f$ is the null, which proves that $G_f$ is closed.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to finish the problem.  Am I missing steps?

Comment: What are $y$, $s$, $U_y$, $U_{f(s)}$, and $U$? You haven't explained what any of these are in your proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $Y$ is separated, the diagonal $D=\{(y,y), y\in Y\}\subset Y\times Y$ is closed. Let $F:X\times Y\rightarrow Y\times Y$ defined by $F(x,y)=(f(x),y)$, $G_f=F^{-1}(D)$. done